# Json.NET does not deserialize property with custom getter and immutable type

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json (a.k.a. Json.Net) for serialization of my class:

```
public class ClassWithCustomProperty
{
    private ImmutableValue value;
    public ImmutableValue Value
    {
        get => value = (value ?? new ImmutableValue(0));
        set => this.value = value;
    }
}

public class ImmutableValue
{
    public readonly int Value;
    public ImmutableValue(int value) => Value = value;
}
```

But when I serialize and deserialize the object I don't receive the expected value:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ClassWithCustomProperty
        {
            Value = new ImmutableValue(42)
        });
        // JSON is {"Value": {"Value": 42}} as expected

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassWithCustomProperty>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Value?.Value); 
        // But after deserialization obj.Value.Value is 0, instead of 42
    }
}
```

What is wrong, or how to change this behavior?

I noticed that if I serialize and deserialize an `ImmutableValue` by itself, it works fine:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ImmutableValue(42));
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImmutableValue>(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Value);  // 42
```

Comment: How would the deserializer assign the value to `ImmutableValue.Value`? it's readonly.  The serialize doesn't magically know how to create an `ImmutableValue` nor that the ctor assigns the value.  It's zero because the `Value` property is never assigned a value on deserializtion.

Comment: But deserializer can assign the value to `ImmutableValue.Value` by ctor.
Try execute:
`Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImmutableValue>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ImmutableValue(42))).Value);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is this line in your `ClassWithCustomProperty` class:

```
    get => value = (value ?? new ImmutableValue(0));
```

Json.Net's default behavior is to reuse existing objects rather than replace them.  So when it is time to deserialize the `ImmutableValue` on `ClassWithCustomProperty`, the serializer first checks whether there is an existing value.  The accessor (above) finds that there isn't, so it creates one with value `0`, which is returned to the serializer.  The serializer then attempts to reuse this existing object, but since it is readonly, there is no way to set the value `42` on it.  So the value remains zero.

There is an [`ObjectCreationHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#ObjectCreationHandling) setting which can be used to change this behavior.  If you set it to `Replace`, it will work the way you want.  Try like this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace 
};
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassWithCustomProperty>(json, settings);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UVDMsL